# Combine group by and count mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find out all statuses in a table using group by:

```
SELECT status FROM table GROUP BY status
```

And then count the results found

```
SELECT count(id) WHERE status = [STATUS]
```

So a table like:

```
+--------------------+
| ID | STATUS | NAME |
+--------------------+
|0001| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0002| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0003| CANCEL | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0004| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0005| CANCEL | JOHN | 
---------------------
|0006| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0007| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0008| SAVE   | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0009| SAVE   | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0010| BOUGHT | JOHN | 
----------------------
|0011| SAVE   | JOHN | 
----------------------
```

Would yield a result like:

```
STATUS | COUNT
---------------
SAVE   | 3
BOUGHT | 6
CANCEL | 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT status FROM table GROUP BY status` is an expensive way to get the same result as `SELECT DISTINCT status FROM table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query:

```
SELECT status, count(id) as CNT FROM table GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by status this will give you desired result

```
select status, count(id) as COUNT FROM table GROUP BY status
```